# test a connection to a network device using snmp

Tags: php, snmp

I have this code to retrieve some countervalues of a copymachine.

```
    foreach($sett as $key => $value){
    if (intval(str_replace("INTEGER: ","",snmpget($ip, "public", $base.$value["MIB"])))) {
        $c = intval(str_replace("INTEGER: ","",snmpget($ip, "public", $base.$value["MIB"])));
        $error = false;
    }
    else {
        $c = 0;
        $error = true;
    }
    $counters = array_push_assoc($counters,ucwords($key),array("total" => $c, "code" => $value["code"]));
}
```

everything works like a charm but the only thing that is the problem is when a machine is down en the code cannot make an SNMPGET, the whole script fails.

First I want to check if the connection to the device is alive and then retrieve the counters with SNMPGET

Is there any solution you guys can offer me?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The `snmpget()` function returns FALSE if it fails to retrieve the object.

See docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php

You should do a check for this within your code, for example:

```
try
{
    foreach($sett as $key => $value){

    $sntpReturn = snmpget($ip, "public", $base.$value["MIB"]);

    if ($sntpReturn === false)
    {
        // Do something to handle failed SNTP request.
        throw new Exception("Failed to execute the SNTP request to the machine.");
    }
    else
    {

    if (intval(str_replace("INTEGER: ","", $sntpReturn))) {
        $c = intval(str_replace("INTEGER: ","",snmpget($ip, "public", $base.$value["MIB"])));
        $error = false;
    }
    else {
        $c = 0;
        $error = true;
    }
    $counters = array_push_assoc($counters,ucwords($key),array("total" => $c, "code" => $value["code"]));

    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Handle the exception, maybe kill the script because it failed?
}
```